# Can I create my own attribute classes in PowerShell 2.0?

Tags: .net, powershell, attributes

I was wondering whether you could create your own .NET Attribute classes for PowerShell and use them in scripts e.g.

[DebugAttribute=true]
function DoSomeThing()
{
    "I don't run in Release mode"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create your own attributes, but only for certain purposes - specifically validation and argument transformation.

From the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.internal.cmdletmetadataattribute(VS.85).aspx):

> Snap-ins cannot create custom
>   attributes that derive directly from
>   CmdletMetadataAttribute because there
>   is no public constructor. However,
>   snap-ins can derive custom attributes
>   from the ValidateArgumentsAttribute
>   and ArgumentTransformationAttribute
>   classes.

I have yet to create a cmdlet attribute and try it in an advanced function though.